# Iterative targeted-FGSM not working for minibatches

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to perform iterative fgsm attack to my neural network. I am refering to this blog https://savan77.github.io/blog/imagenet_adv_examples.html. However, the attack can only affect the prediction of the first data in a minibatch. And the resting is not affected.

I am using MNIST dataset and a very small neural network, which I have pretrained by myself.

```py
def fgsm_attack(inputs, model, epsilon, attacked_target):
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    inputs_tensor = inputs.data
    alpha = 0.025

    # Add iterations to make attack stronger
    for i in range(5):
        zero_gradients(inputs)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss_gen = criterion(outputs, attacked_targets)
        loss_gen.backward(retain_graph=True)

        # Collect the element-wise sign of the data gradient
        sign_inputs_grad = alpha * torch.sign(inputs.grad.data)

        # I am performing targeted attack, so this is minus
        adv_temp = inputs.data - sign_inputs_grad

        total_grad = adv_temp - inputs_tensor

        # Just to ensure that the amplitude will not exceed the threshold
        total_grad = torch.clamp(total_grad, -epsilon, epsilon)

        x_adv = inputs_tensor + total_grad
        inputs.data = x_adv

    return inputs, total_grad
```

If the batch size is 5:

If there is no attack, the predictions should be [7, 4, 6, 5, 0]

If we set the attacked target to be 1, the expected results should be [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

However, I got [1, 4, 6, 5, 0].

This is how I generate the adversaries:

```py
for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(val_loader):
    inputs.requires_grad = True
    perturbed_inputs, sign_inputs_grad = fgsm_attack(inputs, model, epsilon, attacked_target)
    outputs = model(perturbed_inputs)
    ...
```

I just call the function to generate adversaries.

Comment: Show us the code from which you generated the example in the end on your question.

Comment: thx! I added the code  where I call this function. It is exactly the same as the process in the link I shared. I just pack the iterations into a function, and raise the batch size from 1 to .

Comment: but there is no prediction in the code you added, and your example was about the predictions...

Comment: sorry for that. But I don't think I am allowed to add to much code to the post?